# softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license not working

Tags: android, flutter

Exception: Flutter failed to run "/Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java -version".
The binary was built with the incorrect architecture to run on this machine.
If you are on an ARM Apple Silicon Mac, Flutter requires the Rosetta translation
environment. Try running:

```
  sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

but

**Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported.**

Comment: What machine do you have?

Comment: macbook pro mac sonoma 14.1

Comment: i find why 
i downloaded apple chip but my mac intel chip version